# What is the opposite of relaxation

Tags: optimization, terminology, convex-optimization, relaxations

If I understand correctly, a given problem:
\begin{equation}
\min_{\mathbf{x}} \mathbf{c}^{\top}\mathbf{x}, \quad \mathbf{x} \in F \qquad \qquad (1)
\end{equation}

is said to be a relaxation of
$$
\min_{\mathbf{x}} \mathbf{c}^{\top}\mathbf{x}, \quad \mathbf{x} \in C \qquad \qquad (2)
$$

if:
$$
\inf{\{\mathbf{c}^{\top}\mathbf{x}: \mathbf{x} \in C\}} \geq \inf{\{\mathbf{c}^{\top}\mathbf{x}: \mathbf{x} \in F\}}. \qquad \qquad (3)
$$

However, I would like to know what is the appropriate term for the opposite, i.e., having found a solution to equation (1) in the subset $\mathbf{x} \in F$, we need to reformulate the optimization such that $\mathbf{x} \in C$.

I am looking for the terminology here, which, for some reason, is not obvious in most literatures I have studied so far (which is admittedly not extensive, I am fairly new to this). Please help.

Comment: How about a *stressification*?

Comment: Should be added that oftentimes a restriction also imposes that $C\subset F$, (which implies that the inf over $F$ is smaller than the inf over $C$). The reasoning here is that we want the actual *solutions* x to also be as close to possible, potentially in the original solution set -- not just the *values*

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I do not seem to find the term 'stressification' in any literature.

Comment: I don't know this area very well, but in general mathematical writing, the opposite of "relax" is typically "tighten", "strengthen", or "restrict".  In this case, my guess is that you are looking to restrict the optimization to $C$.  (But then I would think that going the other way would be an "extension", rather than a "relaxation".)

Comment: @All : indeed, 'restriction' seems to be the consensus. I even found some examples here, [Sigmund et. al., 1998] uses it for topology optimization or a more general usage is given in [Shwartz 2011].

Comment: [Sigmund et. al., 1998]: Sigmund, Ole, and Joakim Petersson. "Numerical instabilities in topology optimization: a survey on procedures dealing with checkerboards, mesh-dependencies and local minima." Structural optimization 16.1 (1998): 68-75.

Comment: [Shwartz 2011]: Shalev-Shwartz, Shai. "Online learning and online convex optimization." Foundations and Trends® in Machine Learning 4.2 (2012): 107-194.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(1)$ is a *relaxation* of $(2)$, then $(2)$ is a *restriction* of $(1)$.

Also, you have the roles of $C$ and $F$ reversed in $(3)$.

Comment: I followed more or less the definition from pg. 1, eqn. (1) of [1], I do not understand how the roles of C and F are reversed? Intuitively, isn't the relaxed problem susceptible to ending up with a higher infinum, given that we are dealing with minimizations?

Comment: [1]: Kim, Sunyonga, and Masakazu Kojima. "Second order cone programming relaxation of nonconvex quadratic optimization problems." Optimization methods and software 15.3-4 (2001): 201-224.

Comment: I don’t have access to that paper, but to guide your intuition consider a simpler situation: if $A\subseteq B\subseteq\mathbb R$, then $\inf A \ge \inf B$.

Comment: Got it, I see the problem, thanks!